# Array transformations

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How can I make this array :

```
Array
(
    [Qualifications] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [description] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )
)
```

to look like this array ?

```
Array
(
   [Qualifications] => Array
        (
            Array [0] =>
                (
                    [name]=> 1
                    [description] => 1
                )

            Array [1]
                (
                    [name] => 2
                    [descrition] => 2
                )
       )
)
```

It was generated via form fields with jquery, then sent back to my server.

Comment: could you show what do you want?

Comment: i want to group my array like the second one

Comment: It seems like there's a language barrier.  What you're asking is not a complete question, nor is there any way someone could answer it.  Maybe try asking the question in your native language and using a translate service like translate.google.com  (and include more detail about your model, your find()...etc

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
/**
 * @param array $bar bar is the qualification array containing (0=>'name' => array(), description => array()
 * @return array
 */
function foo(array $bar = array()){
    $finalArray = array();

    foreach($bar as $key => $value){
        foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue){
             $finalArray[$innerKey][$key] = $innerValue;
        }
    }
    return $finalArray;
}
```

So you pass the inner array (what is in qualification), all you have to do is to put it back in qualification at then end.

EDIT : Without function :

```
$baseArray = array(Qualifications => array('name' => array(1,2), 'description' => array(1,2)));    

$bar = $baseArray['Qualifications'];

$transformedArray = array();
foreach($bar as $key => $value){
        foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue){
             $transformedArray [$innerKey][$key] = $innerValue;
        }
    }
$theArrayYouWant = array('Qualification' => $transformedArray);
```

Comment: err say it again hugo? if i dont want to create function?

Comment: just do the exact same thing without the lines `function foo()` and `return $array`